# Where can I find the definition of SMI, SCI pins on a CPU?

Tags: cpu, processor

I am trying to understand the SMI (System Management Interrupt) and SCI (System Control Interrupt) in IA32 architecture.

According to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40583848/differences-among-various-interrupts-sci-smi-nmi-and-normal-interrupt), it seems a CPU should have dedicated pins for SMI and SCI.

I guess some cpu specs should cover this. I tried some cpu datasheets, but no luck. In those specs, I can find pin names like below, but I didn't see SMI or SCI pins.

[image]

Anyone knows where I can find the definitions of such pins? If I can see it, I will know it better.

Comment: according to that thread SCI and SMI are normal interrupts routed via a programmable interrupt controller or similar hardware

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SMI is generated for hardware faults. As most communication between the CPU and other components is packet-based, faults can be signalled using error packets, and the SMI is then generated internally. A dedicated pin exists if there is an interface that is not packet-based that needs to signal hardware faults that may be recoverable -- typically that means a memory interface.

SCI is an implementation detail of ACPI. The ACPI virtual machine has read and write access to hardware, but no dedicated "enter system management mode" instruction, so there is a system controller that provides a register that will trigger an SCI when written to. The BIOS sets up an appropriate handler and provides wrapper code in ACPI AML for those functions that are handled outside the OS context (mostly, suspend/resume/reset/poweroff). From the OS point of view, suspending the computer is writing a value to a "suspend controller". If the controller is implemented inside the CPU, there is no need to have a physical pin here either.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a package datasheet for a package with an SMI pin: http://download.intel.com/support/processors/celeron/sb/29074802.pdf

It is not neccessary to have an SMI pin to get SMI interupts: SMI interupts can be handled through a seperate interupt controller, and come through the interupt controller bus.

There is, of course, no "SCI" pin: an interupt is /the/ SCI interupt if the system generates an interupt for "Advanced Configuration and Power Interface" events, and does "Advanced Configuration and Power Interface" events when that interupt is generated.

Comment: Thanks. And also thanks to @SimonRichter, the SCI and SMI are concepts of two different domains. SMI is physical and SCI is logical and can be on top of any physical interrupts.